# Validation error in Django's CheckboxSelectMultiple

Tags: django, forms, validation, django-forms

I'm trying to use checkboxes in my app, but Django form validation tells me the input is invalid, regardless of what checkboxes are checked.

In models:

```
AV_CHOICES = (
    ('PC', 'PC Laptop ($150)'),
    ('32', '32" LCD Monitor ($150)'),
    ('40', '40" LCD Monitor ($200)'),
)

Optional_AV_Requests = models.TextField(blank=True, choices=AV_CHOICES)
```

In forms.py

```
class Fair_Logistical_Data1Form(forms.ModelForm):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Fair_Logistical_Data1Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['Optional_AV_Requests'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,choices=self.fields['Optional_AV_Requests'].choices)
```

No matter which checkbox I select, I get an inlin error saying something like "u'PC' is not a valid choice". Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [radio button](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect) for one-choice select. `MultipleChoiceField` returns list of chosen elements, which isn't correct type for a `TextField`.

Comment: I want to be able to select none, one, or more than one element

Comment: Have you considered making `OptionalAV` a model and store `requests` as a `ManyToManyField`?